# Scaling out with 200+ Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, distributed-system

I'm trying to understand how to dynamically scale out application which consumes a huge number of topics (unfortunately I can't reduce their number - by design each topic is for particular type of data).

[image]

I want my application cluster to share the load from all 200+ topics. E.g when a new app node added to the cluster, it should "steal" some topics subscriptions from old nodes, so the load become evenly distributed again.

As far as I understand, Kafka partinions/consumer groups help to parallelize a topic, not to share a load between multiple topics.

Comment: Can you have all your apps subscribe to all 200+ topics with a regex subscription? Then they can all be in one consumer group

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all your App instances use the same Kafka Consumer Group (via group.id). In this case you actually have an even distribution you want. When a new App instance is added, consumer group is going to rebalance and make sure the load is distributed.

Also, when a new topic/partition is created it'll take consumer up to "metadata.max.age.ms" (default is 5 minutes) to start consuming from it. Make sure to set "auto.offset.reset" to "earliest" to not miss any data.

Finally, you might want to use a regex to subscribe to all those topics (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

A Kafka Topic is a grouping of messages of a similar type, so you probably have 200+ types of messages that have be consumed by 200+ types of consumers (even if one consumer may be able to handle several types, logically you have 200+ different handlings).

Kafka Partitions is a way to parallelize the consumption of the messages from one Topic. Each Partition will be fully consumed by one consumer in a consumer group bound to the topic, therefore the total number of partitions for a topic needs to be at least the same as the number of consumers in a consumer group to make sense of the partitioning feature.

So here you would have 200+ Topics, each having N partitions (where N greater or equal to your expected Max number of applications) and each application should consume from all 200+ Topics. Consumers have to label themselves with a consumer group name, each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. All consumers can use the same consumer group.

See [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers) for an even better explanation...